# DNN: creating a new authentication provider

Tags: authentication, dotnetnuke

I've created a new authentication provider for DNN. Everything is working well, but I was wondering if anyone can tell me if there's a way for my login.ascx user control to be rendered next to the social providers.

[image: Current]

And here's how it's shown when the tab for the custom provider is clicked:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

After searching the code, it seems like social login controls (ie, controls that extend the OAuthLoginBase) will be added to a special collection:

https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/blob/development/Website/DesktopModules/Admin/Authentication/Login.ascx.cs#L462

So, I guess there's no easy way to change the looks of my form...